# SQL exclude row from distinct

Tags: sql-server-2012, distinct

It is necessary to apply distinct but exclude one column. output any value from the selected distinct to the value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(orders.surname + ' ' + orders.name + ' ' + orders.middlename) AS FIO, organization 
FROM orders
```

Result:

```
    FIO   | organization
    ------+---------------
    Ivan  | bmw
    Ivan  | bmw
    Ivan  | audi
```

Expected result: Ivan + any value

Comment: Drop the parentheses after `DISTINCT` and your query should work.  Can you add sample data which actually has all name components?

Comment: @zaknafein, DISTINCT is not a function